# Cannot Reach Breakpoint / Intent Will Not Launch

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm attempting to launch an intent in my Home.java:

```
@Override
public void onVideoClicked(Video video) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(video.getUrl()));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It should be initiated by:

```
package com.idg.omv.ui;

import com.idg.omv.domain.Video;

public interface VideoClickListener {

    public void onVideoClicked(Video video);

}
```

which is initiated by `listView.setOnVideoClickListener(this);` in my Home.java

However I cannot seem to reach onVideoClicked when setting a breakpoint in Home.java and I'm unsure why.

FULL SOURCE:

```
public class Home extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements

VideoClickListener {
    // A reference to our list that will hold the video details
    private VideosListView listView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyC0Te2pyooXzuyLaE6_SsFlITKCwjj55fI";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    private int mCurrentTabPosition = NO_CURRENT_POSITION;
    private static final int NO_CURRENT_POSITION = -1;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    ScrollView mainScrollView;
    Button fav_up_btn1;
    Button fav_dwn_btn1;
    String TAG = "DEBUG THIS";
    String PLAYLIST = "idconex";
    Activity activity;
    int imageArray[];
    String[] stringArray;

    private OnPageChangeListener mPageChangeListener;
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        // get list items from strings.xml
        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

        // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
        drawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
        R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
        );
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        //mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.groupScrollView);
        listView = (VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView);
        // Here we are adding this activity as a listener for when any row in
        // the List is 'clicked'
        // The activity will be sent back the video that has been pressed to do
        // whatever it wants with
        // in this case we will retrieve the URL of the video and fire off an
        // intent to view it
        listView.setOnVideoClickListener(this);
        new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, PLAYLIST).execute();

    }




    Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            populateListWithVideos(msg);
        };
    };

    private void populateListWithVideos(Message msg) {
        Library lib = (Library) msg.getData().get(
                GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.LIBRARY);
        listView.setVideos(lib.getVideos());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        responseHandler = null;
        super.onStop();
    }

    // This is the interface method that is called when a video in the listview
    // is clicked!
    // The interface is a contract between this activity and the listview

    @Override
    public void onVideoClicked(Video video) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(video.getUrl()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns
        // true
        // then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] mImages,
                String[] stringArra) {
            imageArray = mImages;
            activity = act;
            stringArray = stringArra;
        }

        // this is your constructor
        public ImagePagerAdapter() {
            super();
            // setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
        }

        private int[] mImages = new int[] { R.drawable.selstation_up_btn,
                R.drawable.classical_up_btn, R.drawable.country_up_btn,
                R.drawable.dance_up_btn, R.drawable.hiphop_up_btn };

        private String[] stringArray = new String[] { "vevo",
                "TheMozARTGROUP‎", "TimMcGrawVEVO‎", "TiestoVEVO‎",
                "EminemVEVO‎" };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = Home.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }

        private final ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener mPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
                onTabChanged(mPager.getAdapter(), mCurrentTabPosition, position);
                mCurrentTabPosition = position;

            }
        };

        protected void onTabChanged(final PagerAdapter adapter,
                final int oldPosition, final int newPosition) {
            // Calc if swipe was left to right, or right to left
            if (oldPosition > newPosition) {
                // left to right
            } else {
                // right to left

                View vg = findViewById(R.layout.home);
                vg.invalidate();
            }
            final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                int oldPos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {

                    if (position > oldPos) {
                        // Moving to the right

                    } else if (position < oldPos) {
                        // Moving to the Left

                        View vg = findViewById(R.layout.home);
                        vg.invalidate();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });

        }
    }
}
```

VideoListView.java

```
public class VideosListView extends ListView implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private List<Video> videos;
    private VideoClickListener videoClickListener;

    public VideosListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VideosListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VideosListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setVideos(List<Video> videos){
        this.videos = videos;
        VideosAdapter adapter = new VideosAdapter(getContext(), videos);
        setAdapter(adapter);
        // When the videos are set we also set an item click listener to the list
        // this will callback to our custom list whenever an item it pressed
        // it will tell us what position in the list is pressed
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    // Calling this method sets a listener to the list
    // Whatever class is passed in will be notified when the list is pressed
    // (The class that is passed in just has to 'implement VideoClickListener'
    // meaning is has the methods available we want to call)
    public void setOnVideoClickListener(VideoClickListener l) {
        videoClickListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // When we receive a notification that a list item was pressed
    // we check to see if a video listener has been set
    // if it has we can then tell the listener 'hey a video has just been clicked' also passing the video
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
        if(videoClickListener != null){
            videoClickListener.onVideoClicked(videos.get(position));
        }
    }
}
```

My Source:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/irab3x18nhj4twt/idg.zip

Working Example:
http://blog.blundell-apps.com/click-item-in-a-listview-to-show-youtube-video/

Comment: where do you set and call that interface method, I dont see it anywhere

Comment: what is VideosListView?

Comment: Check that your `onItemClick` listener in `VideoListView` is getting called.

Comment: I set a breakpoint there just now - it is not reached

Comment: The OnItemClickListener is only set when Videos are set on the ListView. Videos are only set on the ListView if GetYouTubeUserVideosTask completes successfully. Does it? Do you have the internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes - I do have the internet permission set - and yes it does complete successfully: I am able to see the thumbnails, as well as the title of the video and the uploader as well as the JSON response

Comment: Do you have any other code, something else might be setting the `onItemClickListener` (you can only have 1). Other than that I would add `Log` lines to figure out exactly what is going on

Comment: I do not... it is VERY strange - it compiles - runs - but nothing happens onClick I've attached my complete source code in a zip file and uploaded it to dropbox - I have no idea what I did wrong but it's REALLY driving me crazy! : )

Comment: Do you mind importing my source when you have a second?

Comment: The child views will always try to handle the onClick event, if they don't then it is passed on to the parent that is the ListView in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If the List has clickable elements like `ImageView`and `Button`, when you click on the list it is consumed by the `ImageView` and `Button` and your `onitemClickListener` is never called.

To make it work add `android:clickable="false"`, `android:focusable="false"` and 
  `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to each of those `Buttons` and `ImageViews` in custom adapter view.

**list_item_user_video.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.idg.omv.ui.widget.UrlImageView
        android:id="@+id/userVideoThumbImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:contentDescription="YouTube video thumbnail"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
   <View android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="2dp"
      android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userVideoTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft = "5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Video Title Not Found"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userVideouploaderTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:paddingLeft = "5dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/userVideoTitleTextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn1"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" 
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
   <View android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="11dp"
      android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Checkout this article for more info
[List view doesn't respond to click](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/listview-doesnt-respond-to-onitemclicklistener/)